# Vim Snipmate or Plugin to Autocomplete PHP Object Syntax

Tags: php, vim, plugins, snipmate

Is there a plugin or snippet that I can use to automcomplete `->` or `=>` by pressing `-` or `=` + tab?

I just can't stand typing `>` all the time.

I tried creating the following snippets for snipmate, but they don't work because `-` and `=` are affixed to the end of a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a snippet for you:

```
:inoremap <expr> <Tab> getline('.')[col('.')-2]=~#'[-=]' ? ">" : "\<Tab>"
```

This is an expression mapping that maps `<Tab>` in insert mode to `>` if the character before the cursor is either `-` or `=`.

See [`:h :map-expression`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3amap-expression).

Comment: I lose the functionality with each restart.  Can I put this in my .vimrc?